# How to identify when a new machine is connecting to a remote client

Tags: windows, powershell, authentication, client, remote-access

Is there a way to identify when another machine is connecting to a remote client in Windows?
PS. I need to identify the connection of a new machine not a new user(session).

My intention is to run a poweshell right after a new machine connects to the client.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Define "new machine".

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a remote connection to a machine and run a PowerShell script? Or do you want a listener on a remote machine and want to trigger a script either on the connecting machine or the listening machine after the connection event?

Comment: I Will explain better, we have many clientes that we Access remotely and What I need is that every time a different machine(a machine from a user of the team) access the client I need the client to recognises when it is being connected to a different machine then The previous one.

Comment: I don't know if it is more clear. If you need some more information, please tell me. Thanks for helping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something you'd do with powershell. But you could monitor logs and parse the data of new connections. And if the hostname has never been seen then it would run a script or whatever. But this wouldn't be a powershell job.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/running-a-script-based-on-an-event

Might just be your answer. Have the script parse the log for hostname or ip address. And place it in a file. And if it isn't in the file already it runs whatever else you needed.  Powershell could be this script. But not your initial vector.

Comment: Thanks Robert!! this is exactly what I need. Now I will just need to find The event that is responsible for the machine connection.

Comment: What do you mean by "Have the script parse the log for"?

Comment: So I discover that on "Events Viwer" from windows on "DHCP Client-Events" -> "Address Configuration State Event" I am able to see the Computer name. I think that maybe what i can do is to add a powershell script to this task that verifies if the computer is different from the previous one. But I don't know how to get this value from the log and also if it is possible to store the name of the previous computer. Do you have any idea of how can i do this?

Comment: Parsing logs is pulling the data you need. So like using `select-object` and `where-object`

Comment: I believe audit (security log) 4624 is what you want to trigger on.

Answer (score 1):

Windows task scheduler also contains various trigger events that can be used to execute a script. 
it is likely that the 'a new machine connecting to a remote client' results in an event in the Windows event logs. 
See this article how to trigger a powershell script when such an event occurs:
[Trigger a powershell script from a Windows event](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes now I just need to discover which event is returned when a new IP connects to the client.

Comment: So I discover that on "Events Viwer" from windows on "DHCP Client-Events" -> "Address Configuration State Event" I am able to see the Computer name. I think that maybe what i can do is to add a powershell script to this task that verifies if the computer is different from the previous one. But I don't know how to get this value from the log and also if it is possible to store the name of the previous computer. Do you have any idea of how can i do this?